# Typescript readonly argument from interface

Tags: typescript

How to make sure `state` is readonly, but not each of its keys (otherwise could have used `ReadOnly`. All of this from the interface, I'm OK with typescript 5 such as const types.

```
export type GameDeviceFactory<State, Events extends { in: unknown; out: unknown }> = (
  state: State,
  emitEvent: (event: Events["out"]) => Promise<void>,
) => any;

const Some: GameDeviceFactory<{a: string}, { in: unknown; out: unknown }> = (state) => {

state = {a: ""} // Should yield
state.a = "" // Should be OK
}
```

[Repro](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDiBDAtsAIsANwEsBjYAMQxJmkQB4BlGDGYAGjgFEDgA7GAM5xQrXgBMhAbzhFeALjgBXXgGteEAO68A3HAiKYC5Ws284AXwB8cALxwAFACg4cAc1YKmLds%20FYiMNx8hg6EwQpB-AIA2gBE%20jCxALoAlLbWAApQEP4CwHQEEERilmyOaTbWGLyI2o6OJBC8bnAMOcAKmDj4xGSU1LR0khgKblCyAObmHNKyRqrqWroJ8yZaFtZ29m7eFdaS9TustnDDCrGx5nAA9NetABb6ADZicIhEwC%20OR8AAdBgnC43O4MR6KF5wABGqAA8gBpRzmIA)

Thanks

**EDIT: also added this**

```
type UnknownEventsInterface = { in: JSONObject; out: JSONObject };
type FactoryArgs<State, Events extends UnknownEventsInterface> = {
  readonly state: State;
  readonly emitEvent: (event: Events["out"]) => Promise<void>;
};

export type GameDeviceFactory<State, Events extends UnknownEventsInterface> = (
  args: FactoryArgs<State, Events>,
) => IGameDevice<Events>;
```

But while you can't override `args.state` if you restructure it like ({state}) you are free to override the destructured one.

Comment: There is no way to mark a function parameter as immutable; a longstanding feature request for this is at [ms/TS#18497](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18497) but it's not clear if or when this would ever happen (it looks like they wouldn't want to touch this unless JS itself implements such a feature).  I can't come up with a reasonable workaround (there's [this](//tsplay.dev/weznKN) but that's just a user opting into `const`ness, not an enforcement from the type system).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sounds good, even if quite verbose. Thanks for the insight.

Also, I added something I found, even thought this is not locking the code.

Comment: @ScreamZ what about [branding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgTgQwHYBMA8AVAfFAvFDKAMigG8oB9CgI0VQC4oAiW5FJgXwCguIAPMAHs4wKKEhQA4ggC2EACIQAbgEsAxhABiCNcGEg0XKFADKwBMAgAaLjnwAKAM7nLjeGzRmLELAEo8OMggANw8aoJIzqaCcozScoqqGtq6+mjkCIzOcCpIAOZQHHZQ9kZQzt5c-rg4pGUVlnhkUJnMTIXBUAD0XaYAFoIArgA2KFAgKhCj9S4QAHQITUxMnT39Q6NQ1NAA8gDSXByhQA)? It won't completely fix your problem, but could help it

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, seems a good idea :-) Thanks @Nullndr

Comment: @ScreamZ can I write an answer?

Comment: Go ahead :) Also jcalz

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-param-reassign ?

> Assignment to variables declared as function parameters can be misleading and lead to confusing behavior, as modifying function parameters will also mutate the arguments object. Often, assignment to function parameters is unintended and indicative of a mistake or programmer error.

It's more about the code style then about the typings

Answer (score 0):

There is also another technique called [branding](https://medium.com/@KevinBGreene/surviving-the-typescript-ecosystem-branding-and-type-tagging-6cf6e516523d) that allows us to achieve nominal typing instead of [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

```
type Brand<T> = T & { __brand: "brand"}

export type GameDeviceFactory<
  State,
> = (state: Brand<State>) => any;

const Some: GameDeviceFactory<{ a: string }> = (
  state
) => {
  state = { a: "" }; // Correctly raise an error
};
```

This is because from `{ a: "" }` is missing the `__brand` property.

But please, keep in mind that this is not a solution for your problems, since you still could correctly assign a new value if you add all the properties.

```
state = { a: "", __brand: "brand" }; // Can correctly assign
```

As other comments pointed out, currently in TypeScript it is not possible to achieve constantness for parameters.